# Traverse an object of arbitrary complexity and apply an arbitrary transform function to its keys

Tags: javascript, typescript

The function is supposed to loop through an object and transform all the keys, no matter its depth (technically, as far as I remember the max depth is 10).

Performance is to be considered, as it's intended to be triggered on every API call.

```
type KeyTransformer = (key: string) => string;
const transform = (obj: Record<string, unknown>, transformer: KeyTransformer): Record<string, unknown> => {
    // implementation;
}

// usage example

const obj = {
    a: 1,
    b: [{ c: 1, d: [1, 2] }],
    e: { f: 'f', j: null },
    h: [1, 2, 3]
};
const capitalize: KeyTransformer = (key: string) => key.toUpperCase();

const transformedObj = transform(obj, capitalize);

// result:

// {
//     A: 1,
//     B: [{ C: 1, D: [1, 2] }],
//     E: { F: 'f', J: null },
//     H: [1, 2, 3]
// };
```

If there's a trustworthy lib that does it, then I'd like to use it.

**Edit:**

Okay, I was told to publish my attempts. Here is what I tried:

```
import {
  isPlainObject,
  mapKeys,
  mapValues,
  map,
  isArray,
  camelCase,
} from 'lodash';

function mapKeysDeep(obj, fn): any {
  if (isPlainObject(obj)) {
    const objWithTransformedKeys = mapKeys(obj, (_, key) => fn(key));
    return mapValues(objWithTransformedKeys, (value) => mapKeysDeep(value, fn));
  } else if (isArray(obj)) {
    return map(obj, (value) => mapKeysDeep(value, fn));
  } else {
    return obj;
  }
}
```

For the `fn` I used the `camelCase` function from the same lib.

Comment: Please may you share your implementation?

Comment: Did you have a look at similar questions such as this one?: [What's the best way (most efficient) to turn all the keys of an object to lower case?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12539574) (please note that you should typically include what you've tried and research effort in your question)

Comment: No, my obj has a random complexity. I've updated my answer providing one of my attempts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a function with a closure over the function for the key. Inside it checks the type of the value.

```js
const
    transform = fn => value => {
        const
            check = v => v && typeof v === 'object'
                ? Array.isArray(v)
                    ? v.map(check)
                    : Object.fromEntries(Object
                        .entries(v)
                        .map(([k, v]) => [fn(k), check(v)]))
                : v;

        return check(value);
    },
    data = { a: 1, b: [{ c: 1, d: [1, 2] }], e: { f: 'f', j: null }, h: [1, 2, 3] },
    result = transform(key => key.toUpperCase())(data);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```